# Track acquisition channels for 302 redirects (/app) to app stores

Tags: laravel, redirect, google-analytics, routes, app-store

We created a smart link [unblnd.com/app](https://unblnd.com/app)

This link detects the device: desktop, iphone, or android.
Depending on the device it goes to the main page or the specific app store.

The link is a 302 redirect which is not indexed.

Goal:
**Include the /app redirect route within google analytics and track the acquisition channels**

Ideas:

- change [unblnd.com/sitemap.xml](https://unblnd.com/sitemap.xml)
- do not use redirect, just go the mainpage
- use google tag manager
- some third party

**Is there some clean, easy approach which is considered best practice?**

More info:

To create the redirect we use this Laravel controller method

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/app', 'LandingController@app');
```

LandingController

```
public function app(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Agent::isMobile()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        else if(Agent::isAndroidOS()) {
            return Redirect::away(config('app.android_url'));
        }
        else if (Agent::isIphone()) {
            return Redirect::away(config('app.apple_url'));
        } 
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: Post your route code

Comment: @sta I've added the route from routes/web.php to the question: `Route::get('/app', 'LandingController@app');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe we found a good answer!

We changed the controller method to always redirect to the main page, but with a query string param:

```
    public function app(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Agent::isMobile()) {
            return redirect('/?app=desktop');
        }
        else if(Agent::isAndroidOS()) {
            return redirect('/?app=android');
        }
        else if (Agent::isIphone()) {
            return redirect('/?app=iphone');
        } 
        return redirect('/?app=desktop');
    }
```

When the main view in mounted in the browser it checks the query params and redirects if necessary:

```
    let app_url = false;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (urlParams.get('app') && urlParams.get('app') === 'android') app_url = "{{config('app.android_url')}}";
    if (urlParams.get('app') && urlParams.get('app') === 'iphone') app_url = "{{config('app.apple_url')}}";
    if (app_url) {
        window.location.href = app_url;
    }
```